# getting UV map from photos to map back onto 3d model

Tags: texturing, uv

I have some high resolution images taken of a physical object that also exists as a 3d model on a computer. From the Images I extract the "physical" texture of the object with some image processing. I want to map this texture back onto the 3d model. Since the 3d shape of the object is known, I suspect that Blender might be able to do that. If this is not possible, might there be some known algorithms for that? Is this a common process?

An example of this would be something like this:
[image]

Comment: hello, could you please show some pictures/screenshots?

Comment: Hi :). Sure, you can project the image directly on your 3D model, by matching the camera. There's helpful software for that like fSpy.